# jQuery to emulate iPhone password input changes textbox to disabled in a Visual Studio web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I am working on a web application in Visual Studio using visual basic and master pages.  I have 10 textbox fields on a child page where I would like to emulate the iPhone password entry (ie. show the character entered for a short period of time then change that character to a bullet).  This is the definition of one of the text box controls:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMID01" runat="server" Width="200" MaxLength="9"></asp:TextBox>
```

At the bottom of the page where the above control is defined, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jQuery.dPassword.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var textbox01 = $("[id$=txtMID01]");
            alert(textbox01.attr("id"));
            $("[id$=txtMID01]").dPassword()
        });
</script>
```

When the page loads, the alert displays MainContent_txtMID01 which is the ID of the control preceeded with the name of the content place holder.

The following is the contents of lib/jQuery.dPassword.js (which I found on the internet):

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.dPassword = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        interval: 200,
        duration: 3000,
        replacement: '%u25CF',
    //    prefix: 'password_',
        prefix: 'MainContent_',
        debug: false
    }

    var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var checker = new Array();
    var timer = new Array();

    $(this).each(function () {
        if (opts.debug) console.log('init [' + $(this).attr('id') + ']');

        // get original password tag values
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var cssclass = $(this).attr('class');
        var style = $(this).attr('style');
        var size = $(this).attr('size');
        var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
        var disabled = $(this).attr('disabled');
        var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        var accesskey = $(this).attr('accesskey');
        var value = $(this).attr('value');

        // set timers
        checker.push(id);
        timer.push(id);

        // hide field
        $(this).hide();

        // add debug span
        if (opts.debug) {
            $(this).after('<span id="debug_' + opts.prefix + name + '" style="color: #f00;"></span>');
        }
        // add new text field
        $(this).after(' <input name="' + (opts.prefix + name) + '" ' +
                             'id="' + (opts.prefix + id) + '" ' +
                           'type="text" ' +
                          'value="' + value + '" ' +
           (cssclass != '' ? 'class="' + cssclass + '"' : '') +
           (style != '' ? 'style="' + style + '"' : '') +
             (size != '' ? 'size="' + size + '"' : '') +
   (maxlength != -1 ? 'maxlength="' + maxlength + '"' : '') +
      //      (disabled != '' ? 'disabled="' + disabled + '"' : '') +
     (tabindex != '' ? 'tabindex="' + tabindex + '"' : '') +
 (accesskey != undefined ? 'accesskey="' + accesskey + '"' : '') +
                  'autocomplete="off" />');

        // change label
        $('label[for=' + id + ']').attr('for', opts.prefix + id);
        // disable tabindex
        $(this).attr('tabindex', '');
        // disable accesskey
        $(this).attr('accesskey', '');


        // bind event
        $('#' + opts.prefix + id).bind('focus', function (event) {
            if (opts.debug) console.log('event: focus [' + getId($(this).attr('id')) + ']');
            clearTimeout(checker[getId($(this).attr('id'))]);
            checker[getId($(this).attr('id'))] = setTimeout("check('" + getId($(this).attr('id')) + "', '')", opts.interval);
        });
        $('#' + opts.prefix + id).bind('blur', function (event) {
            if (opts.debug) console.log('event: blur [' + getId($(this).attr('id')) + ']');
            clearTimeout(checker[getId($(this).attr('id'))]);
        });

        setTimeout("check('" + id + "', '', true);", opts.interval);
    });

    getId = function (id) {
        var pattern = opts.prefix + '(.*)';
        var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
        regex.exec(id);
        id = RegExp.$1;

        return id;
    }

    setPassword = function (id, str) {
        if (opts.debug) console.log('setPassword: [' + id + ']');

        var tmp = '';
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == unescape(opts.replacement)) {
                tmp = tmp + $('#' + id).val().charAt(i);
            }
            else {
                tmp = tmp + str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        $('#' + id).val(tmp);
    }

    check = function (id, oldValue, initialCall) {
        if (opts.debug) console.log('check: [' + id + ']');

        var bullets = $('#' + opts.prefix + id).val();

        if (oldValue != bullets) {
            setPassword(id, bullets);
            if (bullets.length > 1) {
                var tmp = '';
                for (i = 0; i < bullets.length - 1; i++) {
                    tmp = tmp + unescape(opts.replacement);
                }
                tmp = tmp + bullets.charAt(bullets.length - 1);

                $('#' + opts.prefix + id).val(tmp);
            }
            else {
            }
            clearTimeout(timer[id]);
            timer[id] = setTimeout("convertLastChar('" + id + "')", opts.duration);
        }
        if (opts.debug) {
            $('#debug_' + opts.prefix + id).text($('#' + id).val());
        }
        if (!initialCall) {
            checker[id] = setTimeout("check('" + id + "', '" + $('#' + opts.prefix + id).val() + "', false)", opts.interval);
        }
    }

    convertLastChar = function (id) {
        if ($('#' + opts.prefix + id).val() != '') {
            var tmp = '';
            for (i = 0; i < $('#' + opts.prefix + id).val().length; i++) {
                tmp = tmp + unescape(opts.replacement);
            }

            $('#' + opts.prefix + id).val(tmp);
        }
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

When I execute my code, the code behind populates the value of the textbox with "123456789" and when the page gets rendered, all the characters have been changed to bullets, which is correct.  The problem I am having is that the textbox has been disabled so I can not edit the data in the textbox.

I removed (by commenting out) the references to the disabled attribute but the control still gets rendered as disabled.

As a side note, the code that I found on the internet was originally designed to work with a textbox with a type of password but when I set the TextMode to password, not only does the control get rendered as disabled, but the field gets rendered with no value so I left the TextMode as SingleLine.

Any suggestions or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to have it so that while you type a password, the last letter is visible for a second and then turns into a bullet or star.

However what you can do is as the user types in password, with a delay of lets say 500ms store the string the user has typed in so far into some variable and replace the content of the password field or the text field with stars or black bullets. This will give you what you are looking for.